# Como inserir várias imagens num único post dentro de um CPT?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-types

Criei um Custom Post Type para publicar várias imagens juntas.

--->>> titulo <<--- 
--->>> imagem destacada/default <<<--- 
  ---->texto<--- 
  --->>imagens<<--- 
  --->>imagens<<--- 
        .....

As três primeiras seções (título, imagem destacada e texto) é o básico. Já está pronto.

Agora, como eu posso adicionar várias imagens neste único CPT?

Eu pensei em utilizar metabox e adicionar a url da imagem. Entretanto, adicionar url por url não é nada intuitivo e dá muito mais trabalho para o usuário, seja ele leigo ou avançado. Além disso, a quantidade de imagens irá variar pode ser 1, podem ser 5, podem ser 10 e por aí vai.

Como posso adicionar várias imagens dentro de único post num CPT?

O Dashboard ficaria assim:

--->>> titulo <<--- 
--->>> texto/content<<<--- 
--->>> imagem destacada<<<--- 
--->>add imagens<<---

Como posso fazer isso? Seja por plugin ou na mão mesmo.

Comment: Esse problema é bem complexo. Você pode resolver através de *repeatable metaboxes*. Dê uma olhada nisso aqui https://gist.github.com/helen/1593065

Answer (score 0):

Zkk,

a opção considerando o uso de plugins é bastante simples e fácil de ser implementada. Existem inúmeras alternativas de plugins disponíveis que oferecem um tipo de campo específico com a característica de ser repetível, que é exatamente o que você busca.

Irei apresentar alguns passos que pretendem abranger de maneira genérica as etapas, independente do plugin escolhido:

1) Escolha um plugin que trabalhe com **campos personalizados** e que possua a funcionalidade de *repeateable fields* (ou *loop*). Faça uma busca no diretório de plugins do WordPress, ou utilize [essa lista comparativa](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mSqienVYxLopTFGLPK0lGCJst2knKzXDtLQRgwjeBN8/edit#gid=3) que já lista várias opções.

> Importante: faça uma escolha baseado naqueles que oferecem o recurso *repeateable fields* - que é uma característica apontada na tabela.

2) Depois de instalar o plugin, o próximo passo será criar um campo personalizado (ou um grupo de campos, dependendo do plugin que você escolher) do tipo IMAGEM que seja repetível (ou então um grupo repetível que dentro possua um campo de imagem que possa ser portanto repetido).

3) Defina nos filtros desse campo/grupo que eles deverão estar disponíveis apenas no seu CPT específico.

4) Agora faça a implementação no seu código. Cada plugin utiliza uma função diferente para retornar os dados registrados com os campos personalizados, portanto, veja a documentação da alternativa que você escolheu. Em `php`, você provavelmente vai receber um array de todas as imagens, e então basta rodar um `foreach` para imprimir cada uma das imagens disponibilizadas.

Boa sorte!

> Obs: optei em não indicar um plugin específico para tornar essa
>   resposta isenta de interesses comerciais, pois muitos deles são
>   disponibilizados em versões gratuitas ou pagas.